# How can I efficiently save and load a big list

Tags: r, list, save, bigdata

***Disclaimer***:
Many of you pointed to a duplicated post, I was aware of it but I believe it's not a fair duplicate as some way of saving/loading might be different for data frames and lists. For instance the packages `fst` and `feather` work on data frames but not on lists.

My question is specific to **lists**.

I have a ~50M element list and I'd like to save it to a file to share it among different R sessions.

I know the native ways of saving in R (`save`, `save.image`, `saveRDS`). My point was : would you still use these functions on big scale data?

What is the fastest way to save it and read it back? (any R readable format would be alright).

Comment: @MLavoie but it is for data.tables not for lists, isn't it?

Comment: @MLavoie OP wants to save a list. I would go for base RDS or fancy feather, fst solutions.

Comment: There is not a single post on stack about saving lists to a file. Maybe instead of giving all the minus you could try to help a little.

Comment: @GeraldT, sorry I read too fast your question :-)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, I updated my question.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research it appears that there is no real alternative to the base `saveRDS` function and not many packages dealing with large lists.

Saving a list as a column of a data.table/data.frame **doesn't works** with the packages `fst` and `feather`, it **works** with the package `data.table`. However when reading it back it becomes a character compelling the use of `strsplit` or its fastest alternative `str_split`.

The only package directly focused on lists that i could find was `rlist`, however it does not speed up list reading or writing from/to a file when compared to the base functions `saveRDS`, `readRDS`.

Benchmarks:

```
l <- lapply(1:10000000, function (x) {rnorm(sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = T))} )
dt_l <- data.table(l = as.list(l))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 5L,
  "data.table"     =  { fwrite(dt_l, "dt_l.csv")
                        dt_l   <- fread("dt_l.csv", sep = ",", sep2 = "\\|")
                        l_load <- str_split(dt_l$l, "\\|")
                      },

  "rlist"          =  { list.save(l, "l.rds")
                        l_load <- list.load("l.rds")
                      },

  "RDS_base"       =  { saveRDS(l, "l.rds")
                        l_load <- readRDS("l.rds")                        
                      }

)

Unit: seconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    data.table 18.30548 18.67964 18.98801 19.17744 19.19791 19.57956     5
 RDS_list.save 16.80936 16.81615 16.86114 16.84012 16.91770 16.92236     5
      RDS_base 16.90403 17.23784 18.62475 19.48391 19.60365 19.89431     5
```